# Ошибка компиляции XCode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, cocoa

Компилятор видает ошибку :
 `Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

Второй день ищу решения проблемы, такие варианты как комбинация клавиш shift+cmd+k не работает? На других компьютерах все работает! В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что в консоли печатается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего в вашем проекте есть два класса с одинаковыми названиями. Если нет, то попробуйте очистить проект(Product -> Clean)

Comment: Так и было, оно ругалось на два одинаковых названия файла в Билде и в самой директории проекта. Очистить билд не помогло, при удалении этих файлов вручную они всеровно появлялись, даже если их удалить с проекта. Решил проблему изменив названия файлов. Но билд всеровно создает файлы со старым названием но конфликта уже нету!

Comment: @Vadim, Тогда можете поставить зеленую галочку, если не сложно?